# Time difference in minutes between two times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

Been struggling to get the difference in minutes between 2 times. One time comes from a field of data type TIME in SQL Server. The other value is a string added to the SQL query. I'm running in SSRS 2008 R2 It looks like this:

```
DATEDIFF(mi, CONVERT(TIME, '23:59:59'), _Travel.Start_Time) AS TIME_DIFFERENCE
```

I get the error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I've tried casting '23:59:59' to a TIME type 'AS TIME' but get similar error. I have tried declaring a variable but SSRS won't allow it. Everything I try give similar error. The time 23:59:59 will always be the same, but _Travel.Start_Time will be whatever is in that field in DB. The output for _Travel.Start_Time is in the format 00:00:00

Any ideas how I can get difference in minutes between 23:59:59 and db value?
Ta

added:

CAN'T BELIEVE IT. _Travel.Start_Time IS VARCHAR not TIME. Have now tried

```
DATEDIFF(CONVERT(TIME, '23:59:59'), CONVERT(TIME, _Travel.Start_Time))
```

but still getting same error. However, have noticed that there are nulls/empty fields in _Travel.Start_Time field

Comment: Works on my machine.. Also running 2008 R2. I executed the query in SSMS btw. Are you sure _Travel.Start_Time is a TIME data type?

Comment: kind of unrelated, but be careful when using the string: `'23:59:59'`.  I see people use it like: `WHERE column > '2014-05-16' and column <= '2014-05-16 23:59:59'` Remember, you can have a time that is greater than `23:59:59`, but less then the next day, because fractional values are permitted, think: `'23:59:59.5` your query will might this row.  I always use `WHERE column > '2014-05-16' and column < '2014-05-17'`.  I find it easier to add 1 day onto the end date and just use less than and forget the entire time issue. if you have to use it, use: `'23:59:59.997'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I see no issue with what you have, unless `SSRS` is the issue or `_Travel.Start_Time` is not of type `TIME`.

See this: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/34432)

Sample SQL:

```
-- Sample with trimming time portion off datetime
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, CONVERT(TIME, '23:59:59'), 
       LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7))) AS TIME_DIFFERENCE

-- Sample with time conversion of datetime
SELECT  DATEDIFF(mi, CONVERT(TIME, '23:59:59'),
          CONVERT(TIME, GETDATE())) as TIME_DIFFERENCE
```

In addition, have you tried converting the db value:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, CONVERT(TIME, '23:59:59'), 
       CONVERT(TIME, _Travel.Start_Time)) AS TIME_DIFFERENCE
```

Comment: CAN'T BELIEVE IT. _Travel.Start_Time IS VARCHAR. Have now tried CONVERT(TIME, '23:59:59'), CONVERT(TIME, _DatabaseSettings.Value)) but still getting same error.

Comment: @user1022772 give me a sample time in the varchar format you have it in

Comment: 17:30:00, 08:30:00. Also some nulls thinking about it

Comment: is this one value in the column or 2

Comment: sorry, one value in the column. Just two examples of output given here

Comment: `SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, CONVERT(TIME, '23:59:59'), CONVERT(TIME, '17:30:00')) AS TIME_DIFFERENCE` works fine, I suspect it's badly formed times that are causing the issue. Test it using `TOP 1` to see if that works, assuming the first row is a valid time.